# Splunk regex how to regex mulitple triple backslashes

Tags: regex, spl

First fyi, i have searched answers and am having an issue finding something that works.  I am an end user (and a newbie) to Splunk and have data from a log looking like this (snippet):

```
{\\\"routepoint\\\":\\\"1234567890\\\",\\\"prefix\\\":\\\"\\\",
```

I want to pull field called "routepoint" with the value 1234567890.

I tried:

```
rex field=_raw "\"routepoint\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"(?<routepoint>\d+)\\\\\\\""
```

and then tried to do a `| table routepoint` but it isn't working.

Hoping there is a better way of extracting this field.  Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

Beachsandguy

Comment: This looks like some devastated `JSON` - can't you fix this instead of fiddling with regular expressions?

Comment: I can ask the splunk administrator, was hoping to get around that.  I'm sure you are right though that it is JSON. Thanks.